# SQL Getting first value from a column and duplicate it in a new column

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

[image]

Hi guys, first thank you for reading and for your potential help.
I'm beginner in Standard SQL and i'm trying to do something but I'm stuck.
As you can see on the picture I have some products with the same item_group_id.
For these products , I want to take the FIRST declinaison value and give it to the other products having the same item_group_id in a new column.

to be more clear  I will give the example for the products I encircled.
This is what I'm trying to get :

```
sku    Declinaison                         item_group_id  NEW_COLUMN
195810 ...multi dimensional sophistiqué_10 P195800        ...multi dimensional sophistiqué_10 
195820 ...multi dimensional sophistiqué_20 P195800        ...multi dimensional sophistiqué_10
```

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I am just lost on what you want to do.  Tables in *text* format would help, as would an explanation of what to do with the other rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to achieve this could be using a `JOIN` clause to reference the same table twice. However, this approach is [not recommended](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-patterns#self-joins) as it computes many more rows than needed.

Using an [analytic function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts) such as [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#first_value) is the recommended approach:

```
SELECT
  sku, declinaison, item_group_id,
  FIRST_VALUE(declinaison) OVER (PARTITION BY item_group_id ORDER BY sku) AS NEW_COLUMN
FROM
  TABLE_NAME
```